# NHL goalies with back to back 50 save regular season games

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl, goalkeeper

[Henrik Lundqvist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henrik_Lundqvist) of New York Rangers made back to back 50 saves in wins against the Vancouver Canucks and Calgary Flames in the 2017-18 season of the NHL.

50 save games are impressive feats for goalies, and are not that common during the regular season. This makes me wonder, how many times in the regular season a goalie has made back to back (at least) 50 saves in NHL history?

Comment: It's more a testament of poor defense

Comment: that's true, but poor defence often lasts more than 1 game

Answer (score 1):

It seems that different sources give a bit different information sources on this.

Directly on the NHL website there is article [Lundqvist makes 50 saves in second straight start, Rangers top Flames](https://www.nhl.com/news/new-york-rangers-calgary-flames-game-recap/c-296563440) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180303165134/https://www.nhl.com/news/new-york-rangers-calgary-flames-game-recap/c-296563440))
which mentions:

> Lundqvist, who turned 36 on Friday, is the first goaltender in NHL history to win consecutive games with 50 or more saves since the stat was first tracked in 1955-56.

However, you can find several sources mentioning [Gump Worsley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gump_Worsley) - basically you can simply search [for the names of these two goaltenders](https://www.google.com/search?q=Gump+Worsley+Henrik+Lundqvist+50+saves).

Several of them cite [this tweet](https://twitter.com/ESPNStatsInfo/status/969809081857961984) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180303165955/https://twitter.com/ESPNStatsInfo/status/969809081857961984)) from ESPNStatsInfo:

> According to @EliasSports, Henrik Lundqvist is the first NHL goalie to make 50+ saves in two straight personal appearances since Gump Worsley of the Rangers did it on Jan. 27 and 30, 1963.

I was not sure where to find some reliable statistics that could confirm Worsley's concecutive 50-saves games.

Comment: I am aware that this does not fully answer the question (which basically asks for full list of such achievements) - but maybe this can still be considered at least a partial answer. Of course, if the prevalent opinion is that this should be a comment, I might try to shorten it a bit, delete the answer and post it as a comment.